# What knowledge about GUI standards/design a test analyst should have?

Tags: layout, gui-design, guidelines

I am a software tester who works on a newly developing software product. Sometimes I feel  the GUIs are not very user friendly but could not justify as I do not have enough facts/knowledge on GUI standards and usability principles (ie:how a good menu should look like etc) .

What sort of a knowledge you suggest that I should gain?
ie:Should it be on usability testing? Usability design? Usability analysis? or anything else?

What kind of formal qualifications (ie:certification exams) I can gain?

Kind regards,
Saku

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any certification on the subject (interested, if you find one!), but start with these books:

- [A Project Guide to UX Design: For user experience designers in the field or in the making](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00295H05M)
- [Designing interfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026OR2W2)

They are quite basic books that will give you a lot of initial information. From there you can keep on going.

Also, don't give feedback like "it's not good". Make measurable comments that can help the designers know: What is wrong and Why is it wrong, so they can work on the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want [About Face 3: The Essentials of Interaction Design](http://About%20Face%203%3a%20The%20Essentials%20of%20Interaction%20Design)

The GUI standards for the various operating systems would also be helpful. Microsoft publishes the [Windows user experience guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) and Apple publishes the [Mac user experience guide](http://developer.apple.com/ue/).  There may also be UX guides for various Linux systems.

Since you are testing it might be useful to look into incorporating some [heuristic evaluation](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/) techniques.

Comment: Elizabeth: A year ago, you "committed" to help start a Genealogy Q&A site at Area51. That one did not succeed to Beta. We've restarted it and now only need a few more Committers with 200+ rep to get to Beta. Hopefully you're still interested and will Commit again to help it. The Genealogy proposal is at: http://bit.ly/U3vnDX - Sorry to leave this comment here, but it was the only way I could contact you.